# How to specify the path to the img file in sass

Tags: css, sass, filesystems

How to specify the path to the img file in sass
[image]

Comment: Just the path? `../img/image.png`

Comment: The problem is that when compiling sass in css, my path to the file is not correctly written in css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're defining the path in main.scss and referring to hero-bg.jpg, the path would be:

'./img/hero-bg.jpg'

In the above format, ./ would refer to the root directory. Alternatively, you can also use:

'../img/hero-bg.jpg'

Here, ../ would refer to parent directory.

Comment: The problem is that when compiling sass in css, my path to the file is not correctly written in css    sass code: header
    background-image: url ('../img/rectangle.jpg') no repeat css :header {
  background-image: url "../img/rectangle.jpg" no repeat;
}   and should be css: header {
  background-image: url(../img/rectangle.jpg) no repeat;
}

Comment: That's weird. I think rather than formatting, the issue here is the 'no-repeat' attribute. Usually, background-image would just have url and no other properties. So, try updating it to use just: **background-image: url ('../img/rectangle.jpg')**